# read multiple text files from multiple folders

Tags: r, file, text-mining

I'm trying to read all the '*.txt' files in the subfolders, but it seems like there is a problem in the loop. Basically, folders are structured as following:

```
branch1    branch 2     txt.file    result I want
1 -------- 2002----------a---------------a
  ---------2003----------b---------------b+c
               ----------c
2 ---------2004----------d---------------d
  ---------2005----------e---------------e+f
               ----------f
```

So, I've been listing directories into the list, like below:

```
setwd("C:/Users/J/Desktop/research/DATA/test")
parent.folder<-"C:/Users/J/Desktop/research/DATA/test"
sub.folders1 <- list.dirs(parent.folder, recursive=TRUE)[-1]
sub.folders2 <- list.dirs(sub.folders1, recursive=FALSE)
r.scripts <- file.path(sub.folders2)
```

Then I tried to find `.txt` files in each folder, then read them all through so that individual folders can contain a single text file. Like I pictured above at "results I want". (I do not want to read many files into a single data frame!)

So from here I tried to read `.txt` files in the same folder using a for loop, but seems like there is a problem in the code I've written.

```
for (k in 1:length(r.scripts)){
  file.name.v <- list.files(r.scripts[k], pattern="*.txt")
    for (f in 1:length(file.name.v)){
      file.read.v <- scan(paste(r.scripts,file.name.v[f], sep="/"),
                          what ="character",sep="\n")
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forgot to give a problem description, but this is something that will work:

```
parent.folder<-"C:/Users/J/Desktop/research/DATA/test"
setwd(parent.folder)

sub.folders1 <- list.dirs(parent.folder, recursive=TRUE)[-1]
sub.folders2 <- list.dirs(sub.folders1, recursive=FALSE)
r.scripts <- file.path(sub.folders2)

for (k in r.scripts){
  file.name.v <- list.files(k, pattern="*.txt")
  for (f in file.name.v){
    file.read.v <- scan(paste(k, f, sep="/"),
                        what ="character",sep="\n")
  }
}
```

**Edit**

```
# create list
l <- list()
for (k in r.scripts){
  file.name.v <- list.files(k, pattern="*.txt")
  for (f in file.name.v){
    l[[k]] <- c(l[[k]], scan(paste(k, f, sep="/"),
                             what ="character",sep="\n"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked out without any error, but the result is not what I expected.  If I run the command, R reads file by file, not folder by folder. Is there any way I can make R to read files altogether in the folder?

Comment: No, r can only do things step by step, but you can group your files into a list, check the answer for an update